# git push to Heroku does not create directory with .gitignore

Tags: git, heroku

So in my master I added a new directory to the root of my repo called `log/` with a `.gitignore` file in it containing one line `*.log`

When I check in bitbucket, everything has been pushed correctly and the directory exists when browsing source.

However, when I do `git push heroku master` all the other commits that I've done before/after the adding of that directory seem to have been applied.. but the log/ directory is nowhere to be seen! Any idea what's this oddness??

PS. Running a checkout of the repo into an empty folder creates the folder correctly, so this is surely a heroku issue, right?

Comment: How are you verifying that the directory is not there?

Comment: the app is broken (it's a Django app and I added the log directory to settings, which don't load any more, stating that the directory is missing); but also heroku run bash --app xyz and just seeing that it's not there..

Comment: Did you follow the commends described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gitignore?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I did - an otherwise empty `log/` directory with a `.gitignore` file inside, which contents are just one line - `*.log`, hmm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a log directory on heroku. As you discovered, heroku will not even create a log directory in the root of your repository. In order to view your logs on Heroku, they should print directly to STDOUT or STDERR and then will be handled by Logplex. See the [Heroku documentation for more information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) on logging. That document, however, doesn't mention that the log directory in a repository won't ever make it to heroku. The [document on the slug compiler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) does state that it will do the following:

> Remove unused files, including .git directories, .gitmodules files,
>   anything in log and tmp, and anything specified in a top-level
>   .slugignore file.

Since this happens as part of a pre-recieve hook, the git repository on Heroku never sees any references to files in  `/log` so the directory is never created.

Update the Django logging configuration to use the console handler instead of a file handler so that logs will go to STDERR.

Comment: That is indeed very good to know - thanks for the link! Though the doc doesn't say anywhere that you cannot under any circumstances create your own log directory if you wanted to, but OK. Will test and accept if works fine. Cheers

Comment: Confirmed that this only happens when trying to create a `log/` directory, same `.gitignore` works fine with `logs/` e.g. So yeah.. just unfortunate this bit is not documented clearly, but otherwise their logging system is clearly the way to go. Thanks again

Comment: The documentation is really lacking on that front. There is some documentation in the slug compiler section that mentions removing everything from logs and tmp which I've added to the answer.